# Eclipse search file not working for .docx files

Tags: java, eclipse, docx

I use the search file function in Eclipse to search where a particular word occurs in my corpus. It works fine for all the text files (.txt) in my database, but fails to work for the .docx files even though this option is included in the Search --> File menu. It seems like Eclipse is unable to read through the MS word encoding. 
Note: My word files are entirely made up of tables containing only text.

I have searched all related articles online but could not find anything relevant to the problem I am facing. Please help.

Comment: docx is a zip containing the text in a zipped XML file. A spreadsheet xlsx does the same, but additionally has shared strings in a separate XML. It might be that your docx contains such "shared strings" not to be found in content XML. Can text outside the tables be found? Look with 7Zip or so in the docx files.

Comment: No, all the text is included in the tables - 3 columns and hundreds of rows. But since you referred to .xlsx files, it might be important to mention that these word files have been created from copy-pasting excel tables into them.

Comment: The Excel origin will be the problem. Using 7zip and extracting the shared strings XML might help for the time being.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't string search work in DOCX and PDF files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74562264/why-doesnt-string-search-work-in-docx-and-pdf-files)