# Why doesn't string search work in DOCX and PDF files?

Tags: xml, eclipse, pdf, full-text-search, docx

Why does `Eclipse > File Search` not find a given string in DOCX and PDF files?

**Obstacle**

When searching for a specific string in all files within my workspace, Eclipse doesn't find DOCX and PDF files containing the string.
It seems, Eclipse file search doesn't search through DOCX and PDF files

**Question**

Is `Eclipse > File Search` able to search for a specific string in a DOCX and PDF file?
If so, what are the pre-conditions?

**Current situation**

- Within an Eclipse Workspace, I have different file types, e.g. .DOCX, .PDF (with text), .XLS, .XLS and .XLM and other more exotic file types.
- Regularly, my goal is to find all files containing a specific string / identifier, e.g. `abc-dd-123.variable name`
- In order to achieve this goal, I use `Eclipse > File Search` (STRG + H), with the following settings:

> - Containing text: "abc-dd-123.variable name"
> - File name pattern: "*"
> - Case sensitive: No
> - Regular expression: No
> - Whole word: No
> - Search in > Derived resources: No
> - Search in > Binary files: Yes
> - Scope: Workspace

**Result**

The search finds the string in many file types, except in DOCX and PDF (with text). E.g. the file search finds the string in XLSX, XML, Java files and various other exotic file types.
I know of DOCX and PDF files in the workspace containing this specific string. I used exactly this string for searching. My expectation was Eclipse to show these files as search results, which it doesn't.

**What I've tried so far**

I've searched multiple forums and seem to be the only one facing this issue. The only other thread I've seen had a different problem setting - the user had Excel-files embedded in his DOCX file, see [Eclipse search file not working for .docx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527232/eclipse-search-file-not-working-for-docx-files). This is not the case with my DOCX files.
When I use the `Eclipse > Quick Search` function, I find the string in PDF files. However not in DOCX files. Notice: In the `Quick Search` preferences, I removed all file types from the `Ignored Extensions`-list, which I wanted to find, including DOCX.
I've used the `Find in Files` function of Notepad++ and received the same result, as with the `Eclipse > Quick Search` function: I find the occurrences of the string in all file types, except for DOCX.

Answer (score 2):

`Eclipse > File Search`, or any string-based search, is looking for the given string to appear as an uninterrupted sequence of characters.  Both PDF and DOCX make no such guarantees.  For example, it is common in DOCX to have a string split into two separate runs (`w:r` elements).  Search in DOCX applications knows to account for such separations.  Eclipse does not.  Worse, on disk DOCX files have the above XML content zipped (compressed) per Open Packaging Conventions.  A text-based string search has no chance of matching correctly.

For PDF files, the issue is similar but with different constructs responsible for the separation.

Since the goal in both file formats is to preserve visual appearance, not content ordering at the character level, neither are guaranteed to contain the consecutive characters found in your search sting.

Comment: Do I understand correctly:"Eclipse > File Search" ist not able to find a specific string within a DOCX and PDF - with a gurantee for finding each occurance of the string? And there is no way to enable this search in Eclipse?

Comment: Correct.  Those formats do not guarantee storage of content strings as consecutive characters as File Search requires.

Comment: @kjhughes - Thank you very much for your quick and helpful answer. It seems I need to find a different way of searching for the strings within the files of my Workspace.